# Scheduling in Python - works fine until it doesn't

Tags: python, schedule

I'm looking for some help with task scheduling in Python. I'm using schedule to run a script ("NQV5_0") at the same time each day (0930).

The below code works perfectly for what I need, except when it doesn't. It will work for 1-2 days in a row, but on the third day at 0930 nothing happens and I have to manually run NQV5_0. There is no error message, and the print statement keeps functioning.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing it not to start on the third day?

```
import schedule
import time
import importlib

launch_time = "09:30"  # time to launch script


def job():  # imports script
    importlib.import_module('NQV5_0')


schedule.every().day.at(launch_time).do(job)

while True:  # below is what happens before launch time while waiting for scheduled job to run
    schedule.run_pending()
    print("\r Waiting to launch at", launch_time, "Time now:", time.ctime(), end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this problem by scheduling it three or more times with just 1 minute or so intervals? That'd be quicker to debug.

Comment: Schedule only runs as long as the script is actually running. So it sounds like after 2 days(or whatever amount of time) your script is being closed by some process.
You probably want to use something like task scheduler (Windows) or crontab (Linux) to handle something like this.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Agree on the use of an OS scheduler, but the OP does state that the `print` function still shows output on day three; so the script it still running.

Comment: You import a library/package/module. Does that module execute on import? Usually, Python will only do a single import, then just re-use the namespace upon a next import, not reload the module (and thus not execute anything in it).

Comment: Maybe You need to use `reload()`. It reloads a previously imported module.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've tried scheduling it with shorter intervals and the problem doesn't replicate.

The script that is being run (NQV5_0) terminates itself at the end of each day, so is started afresh each day. It executes on import. 

The namespace comment might have something to it, although if that were the case then I guess it wouldn't run the second time? 

May just be simpler to use task scheduler to get this done.